How 21 letter size string could settle into 16 bytes of RAM
C:
char kral[16] = "Kral "iyidir"";
char kralis[] = "Heheheha";
strcat(kral, kralis);
printf("%ld, %s", sizeof(kral), kral);
In this code I thought it will throw stack error, but it runs without error.But when I change array size of kral to 15, it throws stack error.
Error:
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
My question is this: How 21 letter size string could settle into 16 bytes of RAM.And if can, why 15 bytes of RAM couldn't?
Getting answer for my question

Moral of the story: Do not expect C code to catch errors like this.
